# STM32F302: Only one DMA channel to transfer 2 registers from ADC

Tags: stm32, dma, adc

I am using the STM32F302 uC family.

I need to use the ADC1 to sample some signals. I want to divide the signals into two groups.
-Group1: Voltages, currents, ...
-Group2: RF signal (125 kHz)

My idea is to configure the ADC with injected triggers. This way the 'Group1' will be continuouslybeing sampled and the 'Group2' will be sampled via a Timer trigger (f = 125kHz).

By doing this, the 'Group1' data will be stored in the ADC_DR register whereas the 'Group2' data will be store in the ADC_JDR register.

My problem is that I want to use the DMA to transfer the sampled data but I have only 1 DMA channel available. So, is it posible to configure this DMA channel to transfer data from ADC_DR and ADC_JDR to two different memory locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No You cant do it this way I afraid.

Injected channels have their separate data registers for the purpose and the data from the injected channel will be stored in the appropriate register.